# Python unpack a Packed Struct in One Line

Tags: python, struct

I've have a 8 bytes long packed string ( bytes ). Which has follwing structure

```
    typedef struct _entry_t {
        uint   start;      
        ushort size;
        ushort id;
    } _entry_t;
```

I want to know how can I unpack the entire string in above format and extract those member values , in easiest way possible ( One line maybe )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [struct package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

Suppose you get the data as `bytes` and have it stored in the variable `input`, then you can decode it with the following code:

```
import struct

start, size, id = struct.unpack('IHH', input)
```

Depending on the platform the C code is run on, you might want to think about endianess (add ">" or "<" as prefix to the format string) and if the struct needs the attribute `__attribute__((packed))`. I assumed that on your platform a `int` ist 32 bits long and a `short` is 16 bits long.